# the Define the Normal Flow expression is used in clean code book of Robert C Martine but I cannot understand it anyone can explain it more clear?

Tags: java, design-patterns, clean-architecture, code-cleanup

I am reading clean code which is written by Robert C. Martin in the 7 section about error handling There is a piece of code that I could not understand it.

```java
    try {
     MealExpenses expenses = expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.getID());
     m_total += expenses.getTotal();
    } catch(MealExpensesNotFound e) {
     m_total += getMealPerDiem();
    }
```

what does it mean?
and it is written that we need to refactor it via special case pattern like the following:

```java
    public class PerDiemMealExpenses implements MealExpenses {
     public int getTotal() {
     // return the per diem default
     }
    }
```

Can you translate it in a simple way for me?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the actual context of how the book presents and discusses this. But it seems like the basic intention here is to capture the fact that per-diems are the default behavior. In the first case, exception-handling is used for something that shouldn't really be exceptional -- that is, an employee eligible for per-diem expenses does not have an itemized list, but you still need to include the expense. It's more natural if the expense report returns a `PerDiemMealExpenses` object in such cases, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: A potentially more useful application of exceptions here would be to catch situations where the employee ID itself doesn't exist.

Comment: it is written that the first one is the following: In this business, if meals are expensed, they become part of the total. If they aren’t, the
employee gets a meal per diem amount for that day. The exception clutters the logic.
Wouldn’t it be better if we didn’t have to deal with the special case? If we didn’t, our code
would look much simpler. It would look like this

Comment: Right, that makes complete sense, and is what I figured they are talking about. So what is unclear about that?

Comment: what does it mean that if the expense of the meal is not found then get the meal per diem I cannot understand the concept of the business logic because my English is not really good and when i use google to translate it the meaning is not meaningful for me can you describe the meaning of the business logic in a simple english words?

Comment: What is per-diem expenses

Comment: Per-diem is a fixed amount of money you get per day, instead of the actual meal costs (iirc per-diem is latin for per-day)

Comment: so it means that if an employee did not have any meals so  she or he can get its salary? does it seem logical?

Comment: Please consider adding an appropriate language tag. It will help people who look for problems and solutions in specific language. Also, it will enable automatic syntax coloring in your code snippets

Comment: @CiaPan This is a question about design patterns, it's not language-specific.

Comment: It should not actually matter whether you are familiar with that term or not. It could be called BananaExpenses, and the fundamental code concept being taught would be exactly the same.

Comment: actually i want to summery this book and teach to other people on the linkdin so it is important for me to get the meaning of the business logic but your advice was really great for me i appreciate for taking your time. i would be glad if you see my posts on LinkedIn about clean code.

Comment: @davidf2281 Yeah, but code snippets are in a specific language, aren't they? And it would be much simpler for a beginner OP to add a language tag than to define a language with a markup within the question (as I did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions make the logic of a method confusing and hard to maintain, and they also cause bugs. Please take a look at the code you've provided: it throws a `MealExpensesNotFound` if there are no expenses. Following this approach, you will probably need to handle other exceptions if the expenses are less than some threshold or, for example, negative. To fix this, Robert Martin suggests using the [Special Case](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html) pattern.

Instead of raising exceptions, the `expenseReportDAO.getMeals` will always return the `MealExpense` object. All you need to do is to incapsulate the logic for your particular case in a separate `PerDiemMealExpenses` class. `PerDiemMealExpenses.getTotal()` contains a default logic in this example. Following this approach, if you need to handle another case, you add another class for that.

The trick is that now the decision of choosing the right behaviour is incapsulated in the `expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.getID())` call. The client's code will stay the same without modifications needed to support additional cases:

```
MealExpenses expenses = expenseReportDAO.getMeals(employee.getID());
m_total += expenses.getTotal();
```

If the meals are not expensed, the `PerDiemMealExpenses` will be returned, with its custom implementation.

This approach will allow you to easily modify your software and conforms to [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) and [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Comment: Possible typo (...)